# Xamarin, How to create a chart inside .xlsx using code?

Tags: c#, android, excel, xamarin, npoi

I have a list of pulse values ​​at a certain time and I want to build a chart from this data

In the screenshot is an example what I want
[image]

At the moment I am able to create an xlsx file and write values ​​to cells, but how to create a chart from this data? I use the NPOI library

I attach a [link to github](https://github.com/StriBog45/XamarinImage/blob/master/XamarinImage/XamarinImage/ExcelHelper.cs) with the function code of creating an xlsx file, filling cells and basic chart

Using the Jason example, I was able to build such a simple chart.
However, there are questions about his appearance
Is it possible for a diagram to make a title?
Also, I would like to designate the axis titles
In the example there is a title of the series, which I would like to remove, if it is not specified, then it is created automatically, if you make the name empty, then there will be only a strip on the side, which reduces the whole chart, how to get rid of the title of the series?
There is also a question whether it is possible to use data from another page for a chart

I also found out that the document does not open, when I try to use "double" ​​in the diagram, I don’t know the reason for this error

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/tree/master/examples/xssf/LineChart

Comment: @Jasonon the basis of your example, I made a graph, but a fairly large number of questions appeared on the appearance of the chart. I updated the question